# What is the proper way to update Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried this:

```
listing = []
entry = [0.0]*2   
entry[0] = 1.0
entry[1] = 2.0
listing.append(entry) # My first entry

entry[0] = 2.0
entry[1] = 3.0
listing.append(entry) # Another entry
```

The above does not work.  The same entry pointer is retained, so updating the entry also updates the [1.0, 2.0] entry of the listing.  I can get it to work with this:

```
entry[0] = 1.0
entry[1] = 2.0
listing.append(entry) # My first entry
entry = [0.0]*2

entry[0] = 2.0
entry[1] = 3.0
listing.append(entry) # Another entry
entry = [0.0]*2
```

But that seems clunky.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Update:  (Which cuts through the chatter of the question this duplicates)
The best way to do this, at least for Python 3.X users, is:

```
listing.append(entry.copy())
```

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. You are reusing the same list object `entry`, and `listing` only contains a *reference* to that list, not a copy of its values.

Comment: While adding to `listing` in your first code you can try appending `shallow copy` of `entry` by `listing.append(entry[:])`

Comment: @chepner, yes I figured that out.

Comment: Try to tell us what the purpose of you doing this is and I am certain we can come up with a "cleaner" way to do it all.

Comment: The main reason it probably seems clunky is that you're thinking "What if I had to do this 15 times instead of just twice?" But if you had to do it 15 times, you'd only write it _one_ time; the only difference would be whether you put `entry = [0.0]*2` inside the loop (so every `entry` is different) or before the loop (so you append 15 of the same `entry`).

Comment: @AntonvBR I am doing many calculations to create the entry values.  Then I add them to a listing of indeterminate size. (They are points used to define a spline.) I am thinking since (somewhere) a new entry needs to be created, there is nothing 'wrong' with my working answer, but the shallow copy suggested by 0p3n5ourcE might be cleaner.

Comment: Best answer seems to be listing.append(entry.copy()), at least for Python 3.x.

Comment: Why is `entry` being reused in the first place? What context aren't you showing that makes `entry = [1.0, 2.0]; listing.append(entry); entry = [2.0, 3.0]; listing.append(entry)` *not* equivalent?

Comment: @chepner entry was being reused because I didn't understand that a copy was not being made.  The context that (clumsily) fixed it was to reassign entry as [0.0]*2.  This apparently overwrote the reference and created a new Python object.  Due to reference counting, the old object still stayed alive in the 'listing' object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep entry as a list (for the purposes I suspect I recommend a namedtuple, though):

You can inline the entry creation

```
listing = []
listing.append([1.0,2.0])
listing.append([2.0,3.0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
entry = [0.0]*2   
entry[0] = 1.0
entry[1] = 2.0
```

use:

```
# not mutable
entry = 1.0, 2.0
# mutable
entry = [1.0, 2.0]
```

Comment: Because you are re-assigning entry, right?